# How to join a table which is derived from a with statement into a larger query

Tags: sql, with-statement

I have a large query which joins many different select queries to create a single table with one of the columns recording current stock. I now need to count the out of stock days in the next 99 days but since inbound stock and demand stock do not have a record for every day I have to create a table which shows the movement of stock for each day in the next 99 days by taking current stock plus the change of stock on each future dates. In order to get to this I have created the below stand alone query which returns the correct results for the change in stock per day, the problem that I now face is that I am unable to join this query to main query.

```
DECLARE @Date date

SET @Date = '2020-12-15'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN DATEPART(Day, @Date) = 1 THEN @Date 
           ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date) + 1, 0) 
        END AS myDate,
        SKU 
    FROM
        BS_BufferSetting
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(day, 1, myDate), SKU
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(day, 1, myDate) <= DATEADD(day, 99, @Date)
)
SELECT 
    myDate AS Date,
    SKU, 
    ISNULL(Amount_IOP, 0) - ISNULL(Amount_DP, 0) AS Amount
FROM
    CTE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DP_Demand ON SKU = SKU_DP AND mydate = Date_DP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    IOP_Inbound ON SKU = SKU_IOP AND mydate = Date_IOP
```

The above query returns a result set like this:

```
Date        SKU Amount
----------------------
2020-12-16  BEX -108
2020-12-17  BEX  0
2020-12-18  BEX -12
2020-12-19  BEX  0
```

Once I have linked this to the main query I will then need to work out how to add in the opening stock (from the main table) and formulate a running total but this is part two of the problem.

Comment: please add the tag for the dbms you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain CTE's like this:

```
;with firstcte as 
(
select 1 as MyColumn
),
AnotherCTEUsingTheFirstOne as 
(
    select MyColumn from firstcte
)
select * from AnotherCTEUsingTheFirstOne
```

so you should be able to;

```
DECLARE @Date date

SET @Date = '2020-12-15'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN DATEPART(Day, @Date) = 1 THEN @Date 
           ELSE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date) + 1, 0) 
        END AS myDate,
        SKU 
    FROM
        BS_BufferSetting
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(day, 1, myDate), SKU
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(day, 1, myDate) <= DATEADD(day, 99, @Date)
),
secondCTE As
(
SELECT 
    myDate AS Date,
    SKU, 
    ISNULL(Amount_IOP, 0) - ISNULL(Amount_DP, 0) AS Amount
FROM
    CTE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DP_Demand ON SKU = SKU_DP AND mydate = Date_DP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    IOP_Inbound ON SKU = SKU_IOP AND mydate = Date_IOP
)


SELECT * FROM ATable A INNER JOIN secondCTE B ON A.Col=B.Col
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help I got it now.